# I'm facing issue while taking the build of the apk the error message is to change in to kotlin's newer version.but even after that error is there

Tags: flutter, kotlin, build, build.gradle

actually i need to build the apk for my project in vscode flutter but the issue is i'm getting this error message

```
 [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                            │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update │
│ /Users/fidausman/Desktop/cape_institutions_app/android/build.gradle:                              │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
```

even when i visited kotlin official page and updated to that also issue is continuing it's like my version isn't compatible to the expected version

i tried what mentioned in flutter fix eventhough the error continues.i'm expecting to know the correct version of kotlin which will we compatible and solve the issue and i will get the build

Answer (score 0):

go to **cape_institutions_app/android/build.gradle** update you kotlin version

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' // Change here
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

or if you are not able to find this, make a new flutter project with same name in any other directory (cape_institutions_app) and go to **android/build.gradle** copy complete file and replace with your original project's android/build.gradle file